# ¿Cómo intercambiar columnas específicas por filas en una data.frame en R? (ver ejemplo)

Tags: base-de-datos, r, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos un poco grande que tiene un esquema parecido al siguiente:

```
data <- data.frame(año=c(2012,2012,2012,2012), delito=c("posesion", "comercio", "trafico", "venta"),
enero=c(13,2,12,15), febrero=c(1,2,4,3), marzo=c(8,8,8,9))

data
   año   delito enero febrero marzo
1 2012 posesion    13       1     8
2 2012 comercio     2       2     8
3 2012  trafico    12       4     8
4 2012    venta    15       3     9
```

Y deseo que quede en una forma como esta:

```
data2 <- data.frame(año=c(2012,2012,2012), mes=c("enero", "febrero", "marzo"),
posesión=c(13,1,8), comercio=c(2,2,8), tráfico=c(12,4,8), venta=c(15,3,9))

   año     mes posesión comercio tráfico venta
1 2012   enero       13        2      12    15
2 2012 febrero        1        2       4     3
3 2012   marzo        8        8       8     9
```

Es decir, que los renglones que se refieren al delito pasen a ser columnas y los meses sean renglones (tengo observaciones desde 2012 a 2017).

Pude hacer algo parecido a lo deseado pero implicó demasiado código, ya que tuve que hacer submuestras por año entre otras cosas. (Si alguien gusta, les puedo compartir vía e-mail mi trabajo). Por ese motivo, deseo saber si existe alguna forma sencilla de lograr lo que deseo.

Cualquier orientación la aprecio mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `tidyr` (dentro de `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  gather(clave, valor, -`año`, -delito) %>% 
  spread(delito, valor)
```

Resultado

```
   año   clave comercio posesion trafico venta
1 2012   enero        2       13      12    15
2 2012 febrero        2        1       4     3
3 2012   marzo        8        8       8     9
```

Saludos!

Comment: ¡Gracias! Intenté usarlo con mi base de datos original y funcionó, aunque con algunos fallos. Más tarde actualizo mi pregunta. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Ya descubri el error y no fue necesario actualizar. Muchas gracias, tu respuesta fue muy util. Saludos!