# Traducir código para trabajar sin el pipe %>%

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código obtenido con ayuda de la comunidad.

[Datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxlsfvecbq04rsa/data.csv?dl=0)

```
data %>% 
mutate(y=case_when(
          y >= 2 ~ "high",
          y  < 2 & y >= 1 ~ "medium",
          y  < 1 ~ "low")) %>%              
mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
mutate(y = factor(y, levels = c("low", "medium", "high"))) %>%  
group_by(y, x, z) %>%
count() %>%
group_by(x, z) %>% 
mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = z, y = prop, fill = y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), 
                position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), 
                size = 3) +
  facet_grid(x~.) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
    labs(y = "")
```

Debido a que estoy trabajando con varias bases de datos y que me gustaría realizar combinaciones de gráficos utilizando `grid.arrange`, me gustaría poder traducir el código de arriba para trabajar sin el "pipe" `%>%`.

Agradezco la ayuda.

**Edición 1**

Estoy intentando también trabajar dentro del pipe y asignar el gráfico por el método tradicional, pero encuentro errores:

```
plot1<-ggplot(data,aes(x = z, y = prop, fill = y)) + 
      geom_col() + 
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)), 
                    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), 
                    size = 3) +
      facet_grid(x~.) + 
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") + 
      theme_minimal() + 
        labs(y = "")
plot1

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'prop' not found
```

Obviamente trabajando dentro del pipe, el objeto que calcula las proporciones no se encuentra. Me pregunto si hay un método sencillo para asignar gráficos mientras se trabaja dentro del pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `%>%` no es aritmético ni es un operador base de R, se lo conoce como el "pipe" o tubería, funciona con una lógica similar a las de las tuberías de unix, la idea es simplificar la escritura de funciones encadenadas. Forma parte del paquete [`magrittr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) y suele cargarse automáticamente en otros "metapaquetes" como [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/). Veamos un ejemplo más sencillo, voy a tomar prestado el código de [esta buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/149133/31764):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(año=c(2012,2012,2012,2012,2013), 
                   delito=c("posesion", "comercio", "trafico", "venta", "venta"),
                   enero=c(13,2,12,15,17), febrero=c(1,2,4,3,5), marzo=c(8,8,8,9,10))

data %>% 
    gather(clave, valor, -`año`, -delito) %>% 
    spread(delito, valor)
```

El resultado final poco importa, lo que sí hay que tener clara como se ejecuta esta sentencia:

1. Se parte de `data`
2. Se ejecuta `gather` sobre el resultado de 1
3. Se ejecuta `spread`sobre el resultado de 2

El anidamiento puede ser mucho mayor, pero creo que queda clara la idea. Reemplazar el `%>%` y escribirlo de la forma tradicional no es complicado, debiera ser algo así:

```
spread(
    gather(data, 
           clave, 
           valor, 
           -`año`, 
           -delito
           ),
    delito, 
    valor)
```

La identación es opcional y solo la coloque para que sea más claro. La escritura en este caso es en el orden inverso: primero `spread`, y luego `gather`. Si pruebas este ejemplo de las dos formas verás que el resultado en sí es el mismo. Comentario aparte: ¿Es realmente necesario abandonar el `%>%`?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Editada la pregunta para corregir la terminología.

Comment: Tienes razón con que quizá no sea necesario abandonar el pipe. Sin embargo, el problema que encuentro es que trabajando dentro del pipe, no estoy siendo capaz de asignar el plot por el método tradicional (edición 1).

Comment: @pyring, el objeto `prop` que viene a ser? que datos tiene?

Comment: He puesto un enlace a los datos por si ayuda. Gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: Revisé tu base de datos y tu código y, al igual que Patricio, no me queda claro cuál es tu objeto prop. Si te fijas, no tienes definida ninguna variable n ni en tu código ni en tu base de datos, así que no puedes llamar prop= n/sum(n) de forma alguna. Si lo que quieres es aplicar alguna función ad hoc, lo mejor es que la definas por fuera de toda la llamada al pipe. Entra a esta liga y revisa las líneas 39-48 para que tengas una idea más clara de lo que estoy comentando https://github.com/LuisAlejandroCG/proyecto_gto/blob/master/delitos1217gto_replicar.R

Comment: Repliqué tu código utilizando sólo unas cuantas observaciones y hay una cuestión que debes considerar: cuando aplicas "prop", no se la aplicas a "n" (no hay ninguna variable "n" como señalo en mi comentario anterior). Ahora bien, si intentas aplicar "prop" a "y", no es posible porque desde el principio de tu código conviertes a "y" en factor y no en variable numérica. Creo que en todo caso debes indicarnos con mayor claridad qué deseas obtener, en términos de depuración de datos (no de gráficos), con tu código. Teniendo eso en claro puedo darte una respuesta con código replicable. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alejandro Carrera. He conseguido entender mejor el funcionamiento del pipe y resolver el problema. Se aprende mucho de vosotros.

Comment: Todos aprendemos de todos. Sería interesante que pudieras compartir tu solución a modo de respuesta para observar cómo obtuviste el resultado que deseabas. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Esta respuesta es **complementaria** a la aceptada, que responde directamente a la pregunta.

De todos modos la incluyo porque podría servir de referencia a algún usuario interesado en el funcionamiento de las tuberías o pipes en R. Sobre todo a no programadores que están aprendiendo a hacer análisis de datos con R.

En análisis de datos normalmente el flujo de trabajo es casi siempre el mismo: partimos de una o más fuentes de datos -típicamente un `data.frame`, en algunos casos una lista- y vamos aplicando funciones que transforman a ese objeto hasta que llegamos a un objeto final que es el que nos interesa. Típicamente una tabla, el sumario de un modelo o un gráfico.

> **Disgresión sobre las funciones puras y los side effect**
>
> Importa entender que hace una función pura: recibe un input y produce un output. Normalmente el input se indica como un argumento de la función y podemos pasar otros argumentos para modificar el funcionamiento de la misma. Esto no modifica lo hace una función pura: recibe un input y produce un output. Si tenemos que aplicar varias funciones sucesivas a nuestros datos organizamos el código para que le output de un función sea el input de la que sigue.
>
> A las funciones les puedo pedir otras cosas, por ejemplo, que me muestren en pantalla un resultado o guarden en un archivo una estructura de datos. Cuando una función hace ese tipo de cosas -es decir, produce un output que no es una transformación, sino una salida a periféricos que ya *no podemos seguir procesando*- decimos que produce un side effect o efecto colateral. Es MUY importante no confundir el output de una función con un side effect que pueda tener. Lo que R nos muestra en pantalla cuando ejecutamos en consola `2+2` **NO** es el output, es un side effect.

## Encadenamiento de funciones en R clásico.

Utilizando el estilo más clásico de escribir código en R hay dos maneras ir realizando transformaciones sucesivas a un objeto, es decir, de usar el output de una función como input de la siguiente.

El más básico consiste en asignar un nombre al output de una función y luego pasar ese nombre como argumento de input a la función siguiente. Un ejemplo simplificado:

```
#rm(list=ls())    #ADVERTENCIA: Borra todo el entorno de trabajo. NO EJECUTAR SIN ASEGURAR PREVIAMENTE QUE UN SCRIPT PUEDE RESTITUIRLO. 
a <- c(1, 2, 3)   #Asigno el nombre al output de la función c()
b <- sum(a)       #Asigno el nombre b al output de la función sum()
print(b)          #Imprimo b en pantalla: esto es un side effect.
ls()              #Imprimo en pantalla los objetos en el entorno: deberían estar a y b.
```

No hay nada de malo en encadenar funciones de este modo, pero al hacerlo hay que estar muy atentos a que los nombres de los objetos coincidan con outputs correctos. Si reciclamos nombres (usar el mismo nombre para diferentes objetos), a medida se hace más largo y complejo el script se hace más difícil rastrear cuál es el objeto que estamos invocando en un momento dado.

Además hay que estar muy atentos a los errores silenciosos. Va un ejemplo:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)   
b <- sum(a)       
b <- b + c        #Error intencional: c no existe, entonces b queda sin cambios. 
print(b)          #Error silencioso, obtengo b, pero no es b que quiero.
```

La otra forma utiliza un atributo de R se basa en la programación funcional. Consiste en ubicar directamente a una función como argumento de otra función y utilizar paréntesis para organizar el orden de ejecución. En este caso el código se evalúa como una fórmula matemática, de adentro hacia fuera.

```
print(sum(c(1,2,3)))
```

¿Qué hace la línea anterior? Pasa como argumento a `print()` el output de `sum()`, que a su vez recibe como argumento el output de `c()`. R así lo entiende y ejecuta primero a `c()`, después a `sum()` sobre el output de `c()` y finalmente a `print()` sobre el output de `sum()`. La ventaja es que se reduce la carga cognitiva del programador: no hace falta estar recordando nombres, el output. La expresión `sum()` y el output de `sum()` son equivalentes, y las referencias a uno u otro son transparentes para R. A efectos prácticos son lo mismo.

Por supuesto, podemos combinar ambos estilos:

```
numeros <- c(1,2,3)
print(sum(numeros))
print(sum(numeros*2))
print(sum(numeros))
```

Acá vemos otra ventaja: la inmutabilidad de los datos. En la tercera línea multiplico por 2 a cada elemento de `numeros` antes de la sumatoria, obtengo el resultado que quiero, pero **no modifico** a `numeros`. Puedo estar tranquilo que `numeros` siempre va a ser el mismo a lo largo de todo el script y destinar mi atención a cosas más importantes.

En estos ejemplos simples este estilo funciona bien, los problemas se presentan cuando encadenamos de este modo a muchas funciones. Estos son los problemas que encuentro:

1. Hay que leer el código desde dentro hacia fuera. El código comienza por el final.
2. Encontrar y corregir errores es más difícil, porque es difícil ejecutar parcialmente la cadena de funciones para encontrar el paso en el que se produce el error.
3. Para funciones con muchos argumentos se hace infernal ubicar bien todas las comas y paréntesis.

## Tuberías

Las tuberías son una combinación de estos dos enfoques. Ordenan la ejecución del código como en el primer estilo: cada línea es una "instrucción", empezamos por los datos, vamos transformando y llegamos al resultado final. Pero al igual que es estilo funcional no usan nombres asigandos con `<-`, sino que encadenan de manera directa output e input.

### ¿Cómo funcionan la tuberías?

La clave es el operador `%>%` que es un operador binario, como tantos otros en R.

> **Disgresión sobre los operadores binarios**
> Lo importante de los operadores binarios es que distinguen un lado izquiero y un lado derecho.
>
> `lado_izquierdo %>% lado_derecho`
> Ejemplo clásico `4 / 2`. Sirve distinguir el lado izquierdo del derecho porque no es lo msimo `4 / 2` que `2 / 4`.

`%>%` hace una cosa muy simple, pasa el output de la función que está en el lado izquierdo como primer argumento de la función que está del lado derecho. Al hacerlo nos evita ponerle un nombre a ese objeto, digamos, funciona como un objeto anónimo. Y nos permite trabajar con un orden más natural:

```
c (1, 2, 3) %>%
   sum() %>%
   print ()
```

Primero se evalúa `c()`, después se le pasa el output de esa función a `sum()` y finalmente el output de `sum()` a `print()`.

### Como mezclar estilos (asignar nombre al output de una tubería)

Si queremos asignar un nombre al output de una cadena de funciones enlazadas por `%>%` podemos usar el clásico `<-` al principio de la cadena o su hermando del lado derecho `->`. `<-` también es un operador binario, asigna el nombre especificado en el lado izquierdo al output de la función del lado derecho. `->` hace lo mismo, pero invierte los lados.

```
sumatoria <- c(1, 2, 3) %>% sum()  #El identado es opcional.
```

Personalmente encuentro más natural asignar al lado derecho cuando estoy usando tuberías, para no cambiar de esquema mental. Entonces usaría.

```
c (1, 2, 3) %>% 
    sum() -> 
    sumatoria
```

El resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Interesante aporte. No sabía que se podía usar el esquema a %>% b -> c con el pipe.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esta estupenda respuesta @mpaladino.